# How to create SFTP service in Windows xp sp3?

Tags: c#, windows-xp, sftp

Hi
 We can create ftp server in Windows XP SP3 OS using IIS ftp server. 
 In my project i need to connect SFTP server so, How can I create **SFTP server** in Windows xp SP3 operation system? Is it possible to creat using IIS as we create FTP server? 
 Can anyone 
provide me tutorial or links to create **SFTP server** in my desktop machine?
 
nrk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CompleteFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/overview.html), which supports SFTP on Windows, and runs as a Windows service. Commercial product btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileZilla FTP Server](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server), which supports SFTP.

Comment: Thanks, as it is opensource I can use it.

Comment: Filezilla supports FTP and FTPS, *not* SFTP.

Answer (score 1):

I use a project from sourceforge called [sshwindows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/download/). It's basically a wrapper around the cygwin OpenSSH library. It's minimal and works a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [WinSSHD](http://www.bitvise.com/winsshd) (by the makers of putty). Simple, easy to use, and free for non-commercial use.

Comment: Citation for the putty link?  Putty is written by Simon Tatham, I can't see any link between him and Bitvise.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to setup SFTP server, the below link explains how to setup SFTP server on windows  machine:
http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/windows/openssh_sftp_server/index.php

everyone for the quick help.

nrk